# Bad display of running project

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a problem with display running project in NetBeans. Designed interface looks like:

[image]

But when project is running, it looks like:

[image]

I don't know what happened. I changed nothing.

Comment: Edit your question and insert the images.

Comment: I need 10 reputation to insert image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Swing look and feel to the system look and feel:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Comment: Add that line at the beginning of main().

Comment: Where insert this code? NetBeans generate this in main:
`for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }`

Comment: It works. I needed to delete code generated by NetBeans